# "OF" usage in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: prepositional-phrases, singular-vs-plural

I have found some sentence starting with OF, but these are for plural subjects.

> e.g. Of the model reconstruction approaches using image data,
>   data-driven categories, on the contrary, perform well for complex
>   objects.

now my question is can I use **Of** for the singular subjects. if I say you my idea:

> Of the reconstruction scheme presented by ABC (2010), the extracted
>   intersection lines are used for model reconstruction.

Since I am not sure whether Of in this case is valid, please let me know how the sentence can be improved.

PS: I want to use OF because in my report, in somewhere in upper paragraphs I have mentioned this ABC's method. Without giving reference to the above paragraph now I want to describe his method in detail.

All comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The word *of* is used with plural subject, because we are generally referring to one ***of*** many.

> Of all the reasons I declined the job offer, location was the biggest deal-breaker.

(There were several reasons, but I am focusing on **one** of those reasons.)

In the sentence you've quoted, the preposition you want to use is *in*:

> In the reconstruction scheme presented by ABC, the extracted intersection lines are used for model reconstruction.

Comment: There is the edge case where you can say: _Of __X__, I will say __Y___. But I suppose that's not that this question.

Comment: @jimsug - I see what you mean. In that context, _of_ is roughly the same as _about_.

Comment: Of that usage, no more needs to be said.